# オタクの僕の弟 - Does the "otaku" refer to me or my brother?

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-の

In the sentence オタクの俺の弟がこんなに友達が少ない訳が(ry (which is the name of the third episode of 旦那が何を言っているかわからない件), does the "otaku" refer to boku or otouto?

In general is AのBのC、always interpretable as （AのB)のC as well as Aの（BのC) and one has to infer the intended meaning by the context? Furthermore, can these possibilities be distinguished by intonation (as in English)?

Comment: From the rest of the sentence I would assume that the little brother is otaku. Any idea what the "(ry" is? I was expecting to see ない.

Comment: Looks like the "(ry" really is not some typo but an actual part of the episode name (judging from a quick google on that). Weird.

Comment: http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%28ry

Comment: I think it's supposed to be short for 略, since they leave the ない off, it makes sense, but weird as to why they wouldn't just write ない.

Comment: @Fireheart251 `(ry` makes it look more nerdy, and that's all about this manga :) In addition, maybe it also works as an sarcasm because the original title is notoruous for its length. Oreimo is the pioneer of those "long and descriptive" titles of light-novels.

Answer (score 7):

Both interpretations are possible, but I think this title probably means "my little brother must have many friends since *he is* an otaku" rather than "my little brother must have many friends since *I am* an otaku." It's just because the former makes much more sense to me. `(ry` is a slangy symbol used by otaku to make something left unsaid. It's from `(略)`, and the implication is "even if i don't say this, of course you know what i wanna say here, huh?"

Intonation or a pause may help to distinguish, but only when someone reads this out loud slowly and carefully. Basically the context is more important.

**EDIT:** This title is obviously a parody of [*Oreimo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oreimo), where a young otaku sibling (Kirino) gains many otaku friends with the aid of her not-so-otaku-ish older brother. I suppose `(ry` is used jokingly to mask part of the original title.

Comment: Sorry, I edited your post but realized I was a bit too quick in doing it, but realized now it's a bit ambiguous. You might want to change it back...

Comment: @bjorn This title actually says 友達が少ない**訳がない** (**there is no way** my brother has few friends). The reference to Oreimo was obvious to me, but I should have explained it more clearly...

Answer (score 1):

『オタクの僕』　の弟

オタクの、『僕の弟』

I can't decide which without more context and background.

You can distinguish them by the intonation and the pause.

Therefore, the answers to your questions are both "yes."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to parse that a bit:

> A:（オタクの俺）の弟がこんなに友達が少ない  My otaku self's little brother has few friends.
>
> B: オタクの（俺の弟）がこんなに友達が少ない My otaku little brother has few friends.

In this case it'd be outright easy, albeit probably discriminatory, to imagine in B why the little brother has few friends (likely because he has very niche interests).

For A, the little brother may have few friends for various reasons (maybe put off by his otaku of a big brother) but without more details it's just plain vague.

So to answer your question I'm likely to think B in this example. But the AのBのC interpretations could vary as the others have answered.

Comment: `訳が(ry` の部分を見逃してません? （元ネタを知っているからかもしれませんが）「オタクな弟だったら本来は友達が多いはず」と言っているのだと思います。

Comment: 読む人にはその部分の意味が分かりかねると思いますので一旦除きました。続きを書いていただけないと。。。訳があるかないか書き込んでいない以上説明はつかないと思います。

Comment: ^ `訳があるかないか書き‌​込んでいない以上説明はつかない...` -- 「～(な)わけが…。」「～(な)はずは…。」は「わけがない。」「はずはない。」って意味で使いますよね？「わけがある。」「はずがある。」を含意している、という可能性はないと思いますが。似たような省略は他にもいろいろありますよね。「～しないと。/ ～しなくちゃ。」（「～いけない/ならない」を含意していて、「～いける。/ ～なる。」の可能性はない）「～したほうが…。」（「～いい」を含意していて、「～よくない」の可能性はない）「～なのでは？」（「ありませんか？」を含意していて、「ありますか？」の可能性はない）とか・・・

Answer (score 0):

> オタクの俺の弟

<del>論理的には、自分のことを「オタク」と形容することは可能ですが、「オタク」は第三者に対して用いるのが普通です。</del>
論理的には、自分のことを「オタク」と形容することは可能ですが、二重の修飾がある上記のフレーズでは、「オタク」は「俺＝自分」ではなく、「第三者＝その場にいない弟」に対して用いるのが普通です。更に詳細な理由はEDITで述べます。

従って、「my brother who is オタク」と理解するのが自然です。

---

## EDIT

> (A) オタクの俺の弟

(A) は質問者が提示したフレーズです。

> (B) (オタクの俺) の弟: オタク ＝ 俺
> (C) オタクの (俺の弟): オタク ＝ 弟

質問者の質問は(A)が、(B) と (C) のいずれかということです。

> (D) 俺の弟

(D)は、「オタク」という修飾語を除いた (A) の基本形です。

このサイトは日本語学習者のものですが、私がこれから説明する内容は、日本語に限定された問題ではありません。他の言語でも同じことが言える論理の問題です。
すなわち、(D) において「俺」と「弟」のいずれを「オタク」で修飾する（あるいは限定する）必要があるかという問題です。

(D) において「オタク」で「俺」を修飾しても、このフレーズ以降に続く主語である「弟」の意味が「普通」には強化されません。従って **「俺」を「オタク」で修飾する必然性が無い** と言えます。

「普通」でない場合とは、「俺はオタク」だが、「弟はオタクでない」あるいは「弟もオタクである」のように、**「俺」を修飾している「オタク」という形容詞が後続の文において、「弟」の性質を表現する上で必要性がある場合** です。
実際には、質問者から与えられた文を見ると、俺の「オタク性」が弟に作用しているとは思えません。

例えば「背の高い俺の弟」という文における「背の高い」でも同じことが言えます。
ここで、「背の高いのは俺」とします。
「俺」を修飾している「背の高い」という形容詞が「弟」の性質を表現する上で必要がある次のような場合は自然な日本語と言えます。

> 「背が高い俺の弟も背が高い」あるいは、「背が高い俺の弟は背が低い」

従って、単に、「背が高い俺の弟」と言った場合で、後続する文で俺の背の高さが弟に何ら作用しない普通の日本語では、「背が高い俺の弟」を「背が高いのは弟」と解釈するのはごく自然です。

仮に、背が高いのが俺であって、引き続く文で「弟」の背の高さに関係しない話題である (E) のような文があった場合は非常に不自然さを感じます。また、何故「俺」を「背の高い」という形容詞で修飾したのかの理由を理解するのに困ります。多分第三者からは、「**お前の背の高いことと弟さんの友達の多いことは関係ないだろう**」と言われます。

> (E) 「背の高い俺」の弟が友達が多いのが不思議だ。